# Creating a unique-per-user passcode that cannot be employed by other users

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I'm developing an iPhone game, and thanks to some backers, I got the funding for finishing it.

I wanted to give rewards to those backers with a "passcode"; they will simply enter the passcode and get rewards in the game.

Of course, any one of them would be able to distribute that passcode to the public...and that's a problem.

What is the best way to achieve something like this? Some kind of one-use password?

My first idea was to connect to a remote MySQL server from my game and check that password if it has been used before etc. But I was told that I shouldn't do that directly, that I need some kind of intermediate platform for it. So for the sake of simplicity, what are your ideas?

Comment: Not adding this as an answer because it's just a random idea I haven't researched... But what about letting Apple take care of the exclusivity for you? Make the special stuff an in-app purchase and grant it to your special people by promo code. Dunno if/how you'd hide it's existence from us plebes, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build some web services yourself to interact with your app.  Alternatively you could choose a service that claims to do this for you - e.g [parse.com](http://parse.com).  Have a look at the 'user management' section of the homepage of that site.  I don't know how stable Parse is but it does look promising for what you want to do, if you don't want to spend a lot of time.  There must be some alternatives out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not certain but i dont think there is an MySQL driver handy for this architecture, so writing directly to a server on port 3306 is out of the question (as well as being a huge security risk for your server). I would probably write some simple rest API (in PHP), server side, and do a REST call to the server from the iOS app, a simple request-response over http(s). The response could probably be an xml file (aka a plist) that you could store in the Documents directory - your cue moving forward that the device has a privileged access to your goodies. The server would interface the MySQL to 'consume' the passphrase. PHP can be setup to be relatively safe (from SQL injections, and other 'bad' things).

Answer (score 0):

These two tutorials by Ray Wenderlich demonstrate almost exactly what you want to do. Set up a MySQL database with a Php interface.

Part one:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

Part two:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service